# Edit Customer Account Information without setting address?

Tags: customer-account

I'm using Magento CE 1.9.2 with all latest security patches applied.

I'm trying to edit a customer's account information to give them access to the 'Trade/Invoice' payment method I have set up. However, when I click 'Save Customer' it says that the 'Address' information is required, and I am therefore unable to edit the customer without entering dummy information into the customer's address - which I'd rather *not* do.

There must be a way to change a customer's account information without having to enter an address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to provide customer address to save customer info such as updating user group. If you click the `Addresses tab` from left nav and see an expanded Address area for customer then you have to provide address (fill in required fields) to pass the address validation [image]

In order to bypass that just click x (underneath **Add New Address** button) which will delete this address instance and that's it, now you can save/update customer info without providing an address.

Comment: There is no such button. https://s17.postimg.org/7pb31f1gv/2016_11_07_11_06_44_Linda_Driver_Manage_Custom.png

Comment: Since default billing and default shipping addresses are different in your case, the close button isn't visible. To make it visible again, you can chose same address as both billing and shipping, then remove the address.

Comment: All I wanted to do was change the user type. That is just ridiculous. Anyway, thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just click on red cross button under the add new address tab and then try to save the address. It happen as if we have clicked to add a new address, then validation do work else if we delete them i.e a user with no address, no validation will work